# How do I create a search function for a json array in php

Tags: php, json

I'm using CURL to retrieve a json list of projects. I'm trying to search each project and echo only the projects that have the search term. If any of the projects json fields match The search term I would like to display that project.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/api/projects");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          "Access-Token: CsdujazxcvSq0w"
        ));
        $proj_srch = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $json = json_decode($proj_srch, TRUE);
```

The json looks like this

```
(
[success] => 1
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1088
                [project_name] => Mission Church
                [project_no] => 1088
                [description] => ries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                [institution_name] => Archdio
                [address] => 35 Ptt Street
                [city] => Suaa
                [state_province] => Suaa
                [country] => Fiji
                [country_code] => fj
                [postal_code] => 00000
                [dio_name] => Dio of Suaa
                [featured_image_url] => https://url.org/media/cd51ec97-2684-6ebb-48c8-89d00b9685d3.JPG
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1100
                [project_name] => Micro-financing
                [project_no] => 1100
                [description] => ries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
                [institution_name] => Missions of Africa
                [address] => PO Box 9253
                [city] => Macha
                [state_province] => Macha
                [country] => Kenya
                [country_code] => ke
                [postal_code] => 87199
                [dio_name] => Dio of Macha
                [project_leader] => 55
                [project_leader_name] =>  Bowman
                [status] => published
                [featured_image_url] => https://url.com/media/31bdace8-a384-832c-3976-666f4d2f7bfd.JPG

            )
```

This is what I tried with no success

```
       if (strpos($json, 'search-term') !== false) {

            foreach ($json['data'] as $key ) {
            echo    $key['project_name'];
            }

        }
```

Comment: What you claim is JSON is not really JSON

Comment: An array. It says so in the dump.

Comment: This makes no sense: `strpos($json` $json used as STRING then `$json['data']` useing it as ARRAY !? When do you use `json_decode();` ?

Comment: I used json_decoade() in the first block of code shown

Comment: Then `strpos($json, 'search-term') !== false` wont work!

Comment: Ok, so strpos is only for strings?

Comment: almost every function that begins whit  `str` is for string type of data. You can use $proj_srch for this test `strpos($proj_srch , 'search-term') !== false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decoding the JSON into an array, which is good, however you need to use array functions from then on. Example:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/api/projects");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      "Access-Token: CsdujazxcvSq0w"
    ));
    $proj_srch = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($proj_srch, TRUE);

    $searchTerm = "search-term"; //Or whatever
    $json["data"] = array_filter($json["data"], function ($v) use ($searchTerm) { 
          foreach ($v as $entry) { 
                if (is_string($entry) && strpos($entry,$searchTerm) !== false) { return true; }
          }
          return false;
   });
```

Comment: Hey, really `strpos() !== 0`?

Comment: What if the `search-term` begins at pos 0? ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions my mistake. Long day

Comment: The only valid version is `strpos($entry,$searchTerm) !== false` :)

Comment: Seem to be working but how do I display the full project name $entry['project_name']; only seems to be displaying the first letter of the project name

Comment: Nvm echo $v['project_name'] works perfect thank you!